# Using after() and before() in jquery for IE7 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

Before anyone say this is a copy of another question, just so you know, I've looked around StackOverflow, but none of the answers suits to my question.

I've been trying to use `.after()` in jquery for IE7 but it doesn't work at all. The element I'm moving doesn't appear at all. even looking at the source, the element is not there, again in IE7.

Other than that all other browser, i.e. FF, chrome, etc, all work of them work properly.

JS/Jquery:

```
$('.item-title').find('.aside').after($('<a style=\"margin-left:240px; width:103px; height:19px; margin-top:0px;\" href=\"#applyDateBlock\" class=\"blue-button scrollTo\">Select a room</a>'));
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item-title">
    <div class="excerpt"></div>
    <div class="aside" style="margin-top: -13px;">
        <a class="scrollTo" href="#roomTable">some link 1</a>
        <a class="scrollTo" href="#tripAdvisorAnchor">some link 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of jquery do you use?

Comment: you don't need to escape the `"`... I've tried in JSfiddle on IE7 with jquery 1.7.2 and it works...

Comment: @Roberto, so when do I need to escape and not to escape?

Comment: @Shaoz, you only need to escape quotes that occur in strings delimited with quotes of the same type: double quotes inside double-quoted strings, single quotes inside single-quoted strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.item-title').find('.aside').after('<a style="margin-left:240px; width:103px; height:19px; margin-top:0px;" href="#applyDateBlock" class="blue-button scrollTo">Select a room</a>');
```